# Infinite dimensional representations of $\frak{sl}_2$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The finite-dimensional representations of a complex semisimple Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ are well known to be classifiable by their highest weight vectors, giving a convenient countable indexing set. I know that the situation for infinite dimensional representations is significantly more difficult, but am somewhat confused by the state of the art. Here I will ask a simpler question: For the special case of $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ are its infinite dimensional representations classified? If they are not is there some hope that they can be classified or is the problem too wild? If it is not too wild can the classifying set be expected to be countable or not? To be clear, I am interested in answers for the special cases of highest weight $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ modules, irreducible $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules, and arbitrary (anything goes) $\frak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-modules.

Comment: I must be missing the meaning of your question in some embarrassing-to-me way.  $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ means $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, right?  Then isn't it true that its irreducible representations are finite dimensional, the representation generated by a highest-weight vector $v$ with weight $\lambda$ is spanned by a finite number of $F^i v$ (since $F^i v = 0$ once $w_0(\lambda - i\alpha)$ is greater than $\lambda$), hence is finite dimensional, and all representations are direct sums of irreducibles?

Comment: One possible answer is the Beilinson-Bernstein localisation theorem. Others much more knowledgable than me will weigh in here but let me just point to https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.01540.pdf which works out some very concrete examples for ${\frak sl}_2$ (both complex and real).

Comment: @ L Spice maybe I'm misunderstanding you but it is not the case that the irreps are finite dimensional. Indeed a  Verma corresponding to non- (integral dominant) is irreducible isn't it?

Comment: Yes. For a specific example, consider the representation on rational functions in two variables, as the Lie algebra generated by $x\partial/\partial y$ and $y\partial/\partial x$. The submodule generated by, say, $1/x$ is irreducible and infinitedimensional: it is spanned by $y^{k-1}/x^k$, $k=1,2,3,...$.

Comment: @EBz, [hmm](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142153), as [foretold](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142144), I embarrassed myself.  I had in mind the analogies: representations of complex groups and Lie algebras might as well be algebraic; and representations of algebraic groups are locally finite, so irreducible ones are finite dimensional.  I guess the (a?) wrong step in my reasoning is that the representations of the Lie algebra that you describe don't integrate to the group (and, in particular, their weights need not be preserved by the Weyl group), right?

Comment: @LSpice I tried to integrate my example above, what I get is the space of rational functions of the form $r(x,y)=1/(\lambda_1x+\mu_1y)+...+1/(\lambda_kx+\mu_ky)$. Unless I am overlooking something, this is an irreducible $\mathrm{SL}(2)$-subrepresentation of the space of all functions. Could you explain your remark about the Weyl group?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142282), I meant only to change the "actor" from the Lie algebra to the group, not the space being acted on. If I'm computing correctly, your [original representation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142155) has as weights precisely the odd integers $\le -1$. If $\operatorname{SL}_2$ acted on the same space, compatibly with the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, then  $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}&1\\-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ would convert each ($-(2k-1)$)-weight space to a ($2k-1$)-weight space.

Comment: I confirm that eigenvalues of $[x\partial_y,y\partial_x]=x\partial_x-y\partial_y$ on this representation are $-1,-3,-5,...$ The Weyl group, which in this case can be represented as switching $x$ and $y$, interchanges these with weights of another irrep spanned by $x^{k-1}/y^k$, $k=0,1,2,...$ But what is the consequence?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142365), a consequence is that there is no representation of $\operatorname{SL}_2$ on your [original representation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142155) that is compatible with the action of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$. In [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142157), I was not trying to critique anyone else's reasoning, only to point out a flaw in my own.

Comment: @LSpice Please understand me correctly too, I am not countering any of your statements, I just want to understand them better. I still do not understand why I cannot take some infinite-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{SL}_2$ and generate a subrepresentation by a single vector. I believe such subrepresentations will always be irreducible and almost always infinite-dimensional, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142383)$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}$, a cyclic representation need not be irreducible. In a representation of the algebraic group $\SL_2$, *a la* [Jantzen](https://doi.org/10.1090/surv/107), it will always be finite dimensional. I now see that there are representations  of $\SL_2(\mathbb C)$ that are not algebraic in this sense; you have given [one such](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142282). But your [original representation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1142155) was instead of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$.

Answer (score 3):

This is completely answered in *Nonabelian Harmonic Analysis* by Roger Howe and Eng-Chye Tan, Springer-Verlag 1992.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I don't have access to the book. Might you be able to say you say in a few words what it says? Are there uncountably many irreps, for example?

Comment: @LászlóSzabados Here's a shorter text maybe useful: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/intertwinings_SL2C.pdf or just google 'principal series'. In short there is a family of unitary irreps parameterized by a continuum.

Comment: You need some assumption on the representations: the standard one is that the diagonal Cartan subalgebra acts semisimply. Then an irreducible representation has weight spaces of dimension one. The representation can be finite dimensional; have weights bounded below; weights bounded above; or infinite in both directions.  There is a continuous parameter. In the book they even classify the indecomposable representations (not a direct sum). The calculations are purely algebraic and not difficult. A key role is played by the Casimir operator (action of center of the universal enveloping algebra).

Comment: @Jeffrey: What happens if the Cartan does not act semisimple. Does the problem then become "wild". What are examples of such representations?